# Accept All Cookies popup on this page/site (AskDifferent) not disappearing after accepting

Tags: macbook-pro, safari, high-sierra, cookies

I have tested in other browsers, Firefox, Chrome, Brave, and clicking on the accept button make the popup disappear as it should.
My problem is that it is not working in  in Safari 11.1.2 on 10.13.6

Comment: I'd try a newer version of Safari - apparently the [latest that will run on High Sierra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history) is 13.1.2 -  DL from https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/15675/apple-safari/old-versions

Comment: That's right. No idea how Safari got downgraded to an older version from 2 years ago. But after replacing sleepimage file (turn off sip, delete, turn sip back on) to fix a sleep/wake problem, two previous security updates from 2 years ago also reported as no longer installed. 2020-005 and 2020-006. Reinstalled these and Safari 13.1.2, and cookie popup started working as expected. It's an old machine.